# Renaming a file using a regular expression and x=${...} in Bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I have a bunch of files which contain prefix codes in brackets. I'd like to turn these prefixes into suffixes, like so:

```
Finance-(4BF)-001.doc   --> Finance-001-4BF.doc
Corporate-(K04)-001.doc --> Corporate-001-K04.doc
```

I previously wrote a very simple VBScript to do this on a Windows machine but now I need to do this on Linux. After some tedious searching I can't find a simple and elegant way to apply a regular expression to a filename and rename it using the regex matches.

So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.doc
do
    x=${i//[\(\)]/}
    echo "$i renames to: $x"
done
```

The output of this is:

```
Corporate-(K04)-001.doc renames to: Corporate-K04-001.doc
Finance-(4BF)-001.doc renames to: Finance-4BF-001.doc
```

I know the regular expression above is just stripping the brackets () out of the filename... but surely there must be a way to match their contents (e.g. `\((\w)\)`) and then use that match in the rename command (e.g. `$1`)?

Also being a Linux novice I don't understand what `x=${...}` is doing, and since I don't know what it's called I can't Google it. I presume it's applying a regex to the string `i` but in that case why can't I extract matches from it like `$1` and `$2` etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The construct `${...}` is called "parameter expansion" and can be found in the Bash manual.

The replacement feature is very elementary and does not support backreferences (`$1`). You can use `sed` instead:

```
x=$(sed -E 's/\(([[:alnum:]]+)\)-([[:alnum:]]+)/\2-\1/' <<< "$i")
```

Note that `[[:alnum:]]` is the same as `\w` in other languages, but POSIX regular expressions don't have the latter. See `man re_format` for details.

Comment: See the [Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF) section of the Advanced Bash Scripting guide for more on the expansion / substitution syntax. [Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) is also another section worth reading.

Comment: That works perfectly - thank you. My only further question is: is there a way to do this with "normal" regular expressions (i.e. not POSIX ones) so I don't have to re-format my regexes?

Comment: @WackGet Use a tool other than `sed`, such as Perl or Bash itself.

Comment: I'm afraid Bash doesn't understand `\w` either, as it uses [the regex lib](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex), which is a POSIX compliant implementation. Perl is fine.

Comment: Although this is a very old topic, I'm curious/confused about one thing.  Aren't group locators/identifiers  (i.e. `\1`, `\2`, etc.) numbered from left to right, and in that case, for `bash`, i.e. in the order in which group parentheses are opened ? If so, why does the substitution string read `\2-\1` instead of `\1-\2`?  o_0 ?

Answer (score 3):

The `${parameter/pattern/string}` syntax in Bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is *not* a regular expression; it is a glob (with `#` and `%` treated specially).

Bash has `[[ =~ ]]` [conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) taking regular expressions, which puts captured groups into the `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` array.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.doc; do
    if [[ $i =~ ^(.*)-\((.*)\)-([^.]*)(..*)?$ ]]; then
        x="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
        echo "$i renames to: $x"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the system you're running, there should be a rename utility that is actually a perl script and allows you to use regular expression. I know in newer Ubuntu version they have such a command, while in my Slackware distro I don't have it.

However, you could try and use it as follows:

`rename 's/-\((.{3})\)-(.{3})/-$2-$1/' *.doc`

Otherwise, you've to rely on sed or awk.

Comment: There's actually two common `rename` programs: [rename](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?rename) in the Perl distribution (which may be pre-installed in Ubuntu), [rename](http://linux.icydog.net/rename.php) in util-linux(-ng) (which may be pre-installed in Fedora).  They're different.  Also there's `mmv` and many others...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.doc; do
  x=${i#*(}
  x=${x%)*}
  echo "$i renames to: ${i%%-*}-$x-${i##*-}"
done
```

Comment: Yes. You strip left and right of the parentheses, parentheses included. Then you echo (when concatenatation is called for) what you stripped off, minus the parentheses around what was inside the parentehses to begin with... Although perfectly correct `bash`, convoluted, difficult to read and does not provide a full answer to OP. And yes, I know this is "uralt".